# Solidus payment integration with stripe connect account

Tags: stripe-payments, gateway, activemerchant, solidus

My question is How to integrate the direct stripe connected account payment APIs in Solidus? I am new to solidus eCommerce platform and I have read about stripe provided the [solidus_stripe](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus_stripe) for payment methods but I unable to configure the application_fees and send payment to stripe connected account.

It would be helpful if you share related topics links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is to review the [usage docs](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus_stripe#usage) of that repo, along with Solidus' own [payments overview](https://guides.solidus.io/developers/payments/overview.html).

I don't know of any examples to share with you beyond the snippets in the repo. I suggest asking the maintainers or [Solidus community](https://solidus.io/community/) for examples if what is provided is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I looked at the document which you provided, there is an option to add Stripe as the payment gateway but not 'Strip Connect'.